# Symfony2 Sonata Admin shows text after creating a new item

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

First, i'm sorry for my bad english,

im using sonata-admin bundle, and adminstrating my own Entity, when i'm creating a new item I have a block of text (the text that i write in the first input) that appears in the top of the Admin page, and it's ugly when its a big paragraph.

Lets say my first input is "Content", so when I write "

This is my content

" and save the item, it says "The item "

This is my content

" has been created succefully", how can I make another input be written in the success message

**EDIT :**

Here is a printscreen :

[image]

```
        $formMapper
    ->add('page_mere1', 'choice', array('label' => 'Page mère 1', 'choices' => array('Podologie' => 'Podologie', 'Podz Pro'=>'Podz Pro')))
    ->add('page_mere2', 'choice', array('label' => 'Page mère 2', 'choices' => array('Pathologies' => 'Pathologies', 'Maladies spécifiques'=>'Maladies spécifiques')))
    ->add('page_mere3', 'choice', array('label' => 'Page mère 3', 'choices' => array('Pied' => 'Pied', 'Cheville'=>'Cheville', 'Jambe'=>'Jambe', 'Genou'=>'Genou', 'Hanche'=>'Hanche', 'Dos'=>'Dos')))
        ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations_gedmo', array(
            'translatable_class' => "Antipodes\SiteBundle\Entity\Pathologie",
            'fields' => array( 
                    'titre' => array(                   
                        'field_type' => null,
                        'required' => false,                
                        'label' => 'Titre.',          
                        'locale_options' => array(          
                            'fr' => array(
                                'label' => 'Titre'          
                            ),
                            'en' => array(
                                'label' => 'Title'          
                            )
                        )
                    ), 
                    'Definition' => array(                   
                        'field_type' => null,
                        'required' => false,                
                        'label' => 'Definition.',          
                        'locale_options' => array(          
                            'fr' => array(
                                'label' => 'Definition'          
                            ),
                            'en' => array(
                                'label' => 'Definition'          
                            )
                        )
                    ),                     

                )
            ))
        ;
    //.......
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a printscreen and code?

Comment: You've got to override the Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController in order to customize the editAction inside which there is the call of this addFlash....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but if you want to change the OK flashbag message after an successful edit you can do this with the _toString() method in your entity.

Open your Pathologie entity and add/edit the __toString() function, example:

```
public function __toString() {
    return $this->titre;
}
```

The save-flashbag would then merge the "titre"-value instead of "Definition"-value into the message.